# How to delete duplicate rows from a table using cursor in oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, duplicates, cursor, self-join

I want to cleanup a table which has many duplicate records in it.In the table, each customer number has many records with different eff_dt(column name).

I want to keep only one record for each customer number.

For this, I will be taking only the cust_nbr records having minimum eff_dt as reference. So, for each cust_nbr in the table, I want to copy only the records with minimum eff_dt on a cursor and then compare this cursor values with the rest records in the table.

I used the below query while creating the cursor:

```
select cust_nbr, min(eff_dt), name, address from cust;
```

but this gives me the below error:

> [Error] Execution (1: 8): ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Please help me with this

Answer (score 2):

Error you got means that columns, that aren't aggregated, should be part of the `GROUP BY` clause, i.e.

```
select cust_nbr, min(eff_dt), name, address
from cust
group by cust_nbr, name, address;
```

P.S. Note that deleting *duplicates* row-by-row (in a cursor loop) is *slow-by-slow*. You'd better switch to some kind of a *set* processing. A simple one is:

```
delete from cust
      where (cust_nbr,
             eff_dt,
             name,
             address) not in (  select cust_nbr,
                                       min (eff_dt),
                                       name,
                                       address
                                  from cust
                              group by cust_nbr, name, address);
```

Comment: Hi..Thanks for your help..But if the other records with different eff_dt has any difference from the cursor values, i want to keep that new record and delete the one in cursor. so, next time, i will be taking this new record to compare the next.for that comparison, i am using cursor.

Comment: You're welcome. Well, if you want to do some additional processing and find cursors to be the most appropriate solution, go for it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the cursor logic is for. I would simply delete duplicates with:

```
delete cust
where  rowid in
       ( select lead(rowid) over (partition by cust_nbr order by eff_dt)
         from   cust c );
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work for you:

```
DELETE cust c
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cust
                WHERE cust_nbr = c.cust_nbr
                  AND name     = c.name
                  AND address  = c.address
                  AND eff_dt   < c.eff_dt)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you have two sets of data that you wish to delete:

- all rows with changes to customer's data (name, address...) **prior** to the latest change;
- all rows **after** the latest change, where only `eff_dt` is changed and all else is the same.

If this is the case you can use two analytical functions in order to find minimal date of the latest change in customer's data:

```
create table test_tab(id number, eff_dt date, name varchar2(20), address varchar2(50));

insert into test_tab values (1, to_date('01-jul-2018', 'dd-mon-yyyy'), 'Name 1', 'Address 1');
insert into test_tab values (1, to_date('15-jul-2018', 'dd-mon-yyyy'), 'Name 1', 'Address 1');
insert into test_tab values (1, to_date('01-aug-2018', 'dd-mon-yyyy'), 'Name 1 changed', 'Address 1 changed');
insert into test_tab values (1, to_date('05-aug-2018', 'dd-mon-yyyy'), 'Name 1 changed', 'Address 1 changed');
insert into test_tab values (1, to_date('10-aug-2018', 'dd-mon-yyyy'), 'Name 1 changed', 'Address 1 changed');
insert into test_tab values (2, to_date('12-jul-2018', 'dd-mon-yyyy'), 'Name 2', 'Address 2');
insert into test_tab values (2, to_date('18-jul-2018', 'dd-mon-yyyy'), 'Name 2', 'Address 2');
insert into test_tab values (3, to_date('15-jul-2018', 'dd-mon-yyyy'), 'Name 3', 'Address 3');
insert into test_tab values (3, to_date('18-jul-2018', 'dd-mon-yyyy'), 'Name 3 changed', 'Address 3 changed');
insert into test_tab values (3, to_date('25-jul-2018', 'dd-mon-yyyy'), 'Name 3 changed again', 'Address 3 changed again');
insert into test_tab values (3, to_date('12-aug-2018', 'dd-mon-yyyy'), 'Name 3 changed again', 'Address 3 changed again');

select id, eff_dt, name, address, -- rn, min_eff_dt
  from (select id, eff_dt, name, address, -- min_eff_dt,
               row_number() over (partition by id order by min_eff_dt desc) rn -- we need the highest minimum date - that is the date when last change in data took place (apart from eff_dt)
          from (select id, eff_dt, name, address,
                       min(eff_dt) over (partition by id, name, address order by eff_dt) min_eff_dt -- minium dates of the customer's data changes
                  from test_tab))
 where rn = 1;
```

You can test the script by removing `where rn = 1` and adding `min_eff_dt` to the second select statement and `rn, min_eff_dt` to the topmost select statement, so that you can see the results of analytic functions.

You can use `delete` as in William's response:

```
delete from test_tab
 where rowid in
         (select rowid
            from (select row_number() over (partition by id order by min_eff_dt desc) rn -- we need the highest minimum date - that is the date when last change in data took place (apart from eff_dt)
                    from (select id,
                                 min(eff_dt) over (partition by id, name, address order by eff_dt) min_eff_dt -- minium dates of the customer's data changes
                            from test_tab))
           where rn > 1);
```